# Show and hide table with filtered content after submit(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, submit

**Szenario 1**
i have a view where a form and a table existing. 
through my jQuery code the "table id ="divEdit"" is at the beginning invisble and should come up, when i "submit id ="btnEdit"" the form:

```
$(function () {
$("#divEdit").hide();

$("#btnEdit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#divEdit").show();
});
});
```

At the beginning it is everything great, the table is invisible and i can insert something into my form, which is a search function that have two inputs which filter my content of the table.

The values of the form will be sent to my Index controller and this controller returns the content of the table.
**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(string Product, string searchString2)
    {
        //List of all Products
        List<SelectListItem> product = new List<SelectListItem>();
        Productlist(product);
        ViewBag.Product = new SelectList(product, "Value", "Text");

        //Compares the inserted Product and S_N with the ProductName and Serial in the DB Tabel Products
        var newproducts = from n in db.Products select n;
        if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Product)) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString2)))
        {
            newproducts = newproducts.Where(n => n.ProductName.Contains(Product) && n.Serial.Contains(searchString2));
            //Saves the Data in DB NewProducts so you dont have to insert it again if the product doesnt exists 
            db.NewProducts.Add(new NewProduct { Product = Product, S_N = searchString2 });
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.ID = db.NewProducts.Max(d => d.id);

        }

        return View(newproducts.ToList()); 

    }
```

But when i submit my form the whole content of the table(unfiltered) is shown. The submit has a male funktion after the first click and wont do anything at all. The table won't update after i inserted new values to the form.

**Szenario 2**

I found out that the e.preventDefault() is the one who stop the updating so i earased it and now my skript looks like this:

```
$(function () {
$("#divEdit").hide();

$("#btnEdit").click(function () {
    $("#divEdit").show();
});
});
```

But that wasnt the solution for my problem. Now he updates my table, but

1. i can see the table just one second
2. when i use the submit the first time in the second he show me the whole table with the whole content(what is unfiltered) and i have to click it the second time to see my filtered content in the table

Do you know how to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Escalationmanagementtool.Models.Product>
@section Scripts {

 <script src="~/Scripts/GetCustomers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 }
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>

    Product: @Html.DropDownList("Product", "Select Product")
    Serial number: @Html.TextBox("SearchString2")  

    <input type="submit" value="Search" id ="btnEdit" runat="server"/></p>

}



<table id ="divEdit" runat="server" style= "display:none">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer.Name)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Choose", "Chosen", "New", new { id=item.Id, idc = item.Customer }, null) 
     </td>
</tr>
}

</table>


@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Search", "Add", new { ID = ViewBag.ID }, null)
```

Comment: When you click on your button, your form gets submitted. If you have a callback to the server, your page will be refreshed, your jquery script will be executed again and then your divEdit will be hidden. 
Or maybe I don't get your problem ?

Comment: You could hide the #divEdit with css code *display:none;* and show the #divEdit on click. Please edit your question and post only the problem and code snippet sample

Comment: @Ela i tried that, and erased in the skript the .hide part. Again after i submit the program acts the same like i discriped in the two szenarios with and without  e.preventDefault().

Comment: @r4phG thats right, in the second szenario after the refresh and one second it is invisible again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found another solution with ajax to show the table first after clicking on submit. Therefor i used the tutorial from Azim Zahir.
You can find it on: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/886473/Implementing-AJAX-in-ASP-NET-MVC .
After i got no helpful response here, i looked for other solutions without writing my own skript. Lesson learned: Don't fokus on one solution ;).

I hope it will help you to find a solution for your Webtool.

Answer (score 0):

the problem to above mentioned points could be as follows-

1.(i can see the table just one second)

here the page is refreshed again which executes the line -
$("#divEdit").hide();
so it hides the table after the line is executed and you see the table just for seconds before the line is executed.

2.(when i use the submit the first time in the second he show me the whole table with the whole content(what is unfiltered) and i have to click it the second time to see my filtered content in the table)

here when you submit the first time the line that is executed is-
    $("#btnEdit").click(function () {
    $("#divEdit").show();
});
so only table shows up and no form is submitted yet to filter the table, it filters only when you click it again. when you click second time the form is submitted to filter the table..

hope this help in solving your problem..